# RESOLVE - Transform if on switch case on GO with specific return

Tags: go, switch-statement

I m trying to transform if statement into swith case in golang. But I don't know how to do for the last statement in comment.
The input

```
    if errors.Is(err, domain.ErrNotFound) {
        return nil
    }
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("when .....: %w", err)
    }
    if state != domain.stateSuccess && !refOnline {
        return nil
    }

    if _, err := f.stream.ad(ctx, domain.QueueRequest{
        ID:                      child.ID,
        Type:                    child.Type,
    }); err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("when....: %w", err)
    }
    return nil
```

The right output is

```
    switch {
    case errors.Is(err, domain.ErrNotFound):
            return nil
    case err != nil:
        return fmt.Errorf("when .....: %w", err)
    case state != domain.stateSuccess && !refOnline:
        return nil
    if _, err := f.stream.ad(ctx, domain.QueueRequest{
       ID:                      child.ID,
       Type:                    child.Type,
      }); err != nil:
      return fmt.Errorf("when publishing child task: %w", err)  
      }
      return nil
```

Comment: A `switch` `case` cannot have a simple statement before the condition expression.  You will need to separate the last method call and error check.